# Trying to make service manager but can't have a python program start in a new process, program path not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, process

So i am trying to make a simple service manager that starts other python programs in their own processes in python. But i can't get it to work, it feels like there is something wrong with the path to the program to be started. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. :)

Here is my folder structure.

```
-lambda
  -has
    -system
      -managers
        -services.py
    -launcher.py
    -config.cfg
  -programs
    -services
      -ui
        -svc.py
        -svc.cfg
```

Here is my launcher.py (the entry point of the program).

```
from system.managers.services import ServiceManager
import logging
import logging_config
import configparser
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("Starting..")

# insert system path
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.cfg")
sys.path.insert(0, config["basic"]["program_dir"])

# start service manager

logger.info("Starting service manager.")
svcs = ServiceManager()

# start a service
svcs.start("ui")
```

There is the services.py file containing the service manager.

```
import threading
import configparser
import subprocess
import logging
import time

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ServiceManager():
    """ """

    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("Init..")

    def run_script_in_venv(self, venv_path, script_path, python_version):

        subprocess.run([f"python{python_version}", "-m", "venv", venv_path])

        activate_command = f"source {venv_path}/bin/activate"
        process_command = f"{activate_command} && python{python_version} {script_path}"

        process = subprocess.Popen(
            process_command,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            shell=True,
            universal_newlines=True
        )

        def print_output(stream, prefix):
            for line in iter(stream.readline, ''):
                print(f"[{prefix}] {line.strip()}")

        stdout_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_output, args=(process.stdout, f"{script_path} (stdout)"))
        stderr_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_output, args=(process.stderr, f"{script_path} (stderr)"))

        stdout_thread.start()
        stderr_thread.start()

        process.wait()

        stdout_thread.join()
        stderr_thread.join()

        return process.returncode

    def run(self, venv_path, script_path, python_version, auto_restart):

        # Start the service in an auto-restart loop
        self.run_script_in_venv(venv_path, script_path, python_version)

        while auto_restart == "true":
            self.run()
            time.sleep(5)

    def start(self, service_name):

        logger.info("Starting: "+service_name)
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read("../programs/services/"+service_name+"/svc.cfg")

        venv_path = "venv"
        script_path = "../programs/services/"+service_name+"/svc.py"
        python_version = config["basic"]["python-version"]
        auto_restart = config["behavior"]["auto-restart"]

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=(venv_path, script_path, python_version, auto_restart))
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

Finally here is the output that i get to the console.

```
INFO: __main__:11 Starting..
INFO: __main__:28 Starting service manager
INFO: system.managers.services:14 Init..
INFO: system.managers.services:69 Starting: ui
[../programs/services/ui/svc.py (stderr)] /bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```